# Method works only in debug mode

Tags: java, eclipse

I have been working on a java program in eclipse and it seems that my codes only work in debug mode. Does anyone know why?

Comment: You really think that with this information we can give a meaningful answer?

Comment: How can we know what's going wrong without seeing code?

Comment: Paste your code here. And tell whats the error when you run in normal mode. Then only we can help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sometimes Eclipse and web-sphere 6 behaving like this. Do perform the following actions

1. Verify that "Build automatically"option has enabled.
2. Delete the class file folder and try to clean the project. Then verify the class folder that has been created?. IF not verify the build path.
3. Backup the source and delete the project and restart the eclipse and recreate the project.

Comment: Thank you very much for answering my simple question patiently. I really appreciate your help!